# Can we use \makecell in Tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow, makecell

I am not sure why I cannot use \makecell
Basically, I just want to have a content centre there. Making my life very difficult.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}Xlcccc}  % Changed from c to X, or remove >{} and change to `l`column.
\toprule
    &  & {\textbf{N}} 
    &  {\textbf{Mean Rank}} 
    &  {\makecell{\textbf{Sum of}\\ \textbf{Ranks}}}  
    % & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}}{\textbf{BCa 95\% Confidence Interval of the Difference}}  
    \\
\midrule
\multirow{2.5}{*}{\makecell{\textit{AAaaaa Example Dataset}} \\ (AA) - \\ {\textit{AAaaaa Example Dataset}} \\ (BB) }
    & Negative Ranks
    & 55\tnote{a}
    & 2.50
    & 34.00 \\
& Positive Ranks & 0\tnote{b} & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
& Ties & 0\tnote{c} & \\
& Total & 10 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\footnotesize 
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can of course use `\makecell` in combination with `tabularx` and `\multirow`. The reason why your code is not working is the wrongly placed `}`. With `\multirow{2.5}{*}{\makecell{\textit{AAaaaa Example Dataset} \\ (AA) - \\ {\textit{AAaaaa Example Dataset}} \\ (BB) }}` you should get the desired result (if I guessed correctly).

Comment: @leandriis. it works thanks...the {} making me headache. Between, how to make the content start at left? I tried `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}llcccc}` already in `llcccc`, but still the content in the middle, and  not move towards left

Comment: The makecell command overrides the horizontal alignment chosen throught the column specifiers. Probably you are more satisfied with `\makecell[l]{...}`.

Comment: @leandriis. Thanks. Do you mean `\multirow{2.5}{*}{\makecell[1]{\textit{AAaaaa Example Dataset} \\ (AA) - \\ {\textit{AAaaaa Example Dataset}} \\ (BB) }}`. It seemed not working

Comment: use `l`  (letter) instead of `1` (number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you don't need any `makecell` in multi-row cell. Just redefine it. Also for column header, I would use`\thead` instead of `\makecel`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight\let\\ \newline}Xl cc c}  
    \toprule
    &  & \thead[b]{N}   & \thead[b]{Mean\\ Rank}    & \thead[b]{Sum of\\ Ranks}    \\
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{=}{\itshape
                  AAaaaa Example Dataset\\  
                  \normalfont
                  (AA) -\\                 
                  \itshape
                  AAaaaa Example Dataset\\                  
                  \normalfont
                  BB }
    & Negative Ranks    & 55\tnote{a}   & 2.50  & 34.00 \\
    & Positive Ranks    & 0\tnote{b}    & 0.00  & 0.00  \\
    & Ties              & 0\tnote{c}    &       &       \\
    & Total             & 10            &       &       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
You maybe like to have more evenly spaced columns' widths and numbers aligned at decimal points. At such a case use of `S` columns specifier (define in `siunitx` package) and wider second column gives what you looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \sisetup{table-column-width=0.1\linewidth,
             table-align-text-post=false, 
             table-format=2.2}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight\let\\ \newline\hsize=1.2\hsize}X
                             >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X  
                             S[table-format=2.0]SS}  
    \toprule
    &  & {\thead[b]{N}} & {\thead[b]{Mean\\ Rank}}  & {\thead[b]{Sum of\\ Ranks}}    \\
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{=}{\itshape
                  AAaaaa Example Dataset\\  
                  \normalfont
                  (AA) -\\                 
                  \itshape
                  AAaaaa Example Dataset\\                  
                  \normalfont
                  BB }
    & Negative Ranks    & 55\tnote{a}   & 2.50  & 34.00 \\
    & Positive Ranks    & 0\tnote{b}    & 0.00  & 0.00  \\
    & Ties              & 0\tnote{c}    &       &       \\
    & Total             & 10            &       &       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it possible to make the first column and second column closer? There is  like a big gap between the first column and second column

Comment: @aan, yes, it is possible. Try to use `X` column for the second colun too. See addendum to answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. Is there a way to make the third column `N` at the middle? Currently, it is like at the bottom. I just want to make it look nicer but couldn't figure out the code.

Comment: @ann, I deliberately push it down, Just remove option `[b]` at all `\thead`s.

Comment: ,Thanks. It works. What is the meaning of `[b]` actually?

Comment: @aan, that `\makecell` had to be aligned at bottom. Similarly `t` align cell at top of cell. Without option (default alignment) is center.

Comment: thanks. It is similar like `r = right`, and `l=left`, `c=centre`. But this does not working for `\makecell`

Comment: @aan, this working. You should check package documentation.